# Starvation vs Latency

Tags: linux, operating-system, microcontroller

Process waiting time for resource (may be cpu) called as starvation.
In micro controller terminology, interrupt latency is the time that elapses from when an interrupt is generated to when the source of the interrupt is serviced.
Can we say both are same? If not what is the difference

Comment: "Starvation" is not the same as waiting for CPU under normal conditions; it's usually taken to mean that a process is not getting CPU time at all (or at least substantially less of it than what it would be reasonable to expect) due to contention of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Latency is the measure of time between generation of interrupt request and execution of first instruction in interrupt handler.

Starvation is a **problem** where the process does not get its required resources, and is waiting for more than desired duration to get its slice of CPU time as the scheduler has allocated the shared resource for another process. Starvation is  caused mainly due to improper scheduling.